# Given a list of triples, return a list with the second element of each triple (If an item is not a triple, return None for that element )

Tags: python

I have to use doctest to run and check the following

```
>>> extract_second([('a',3,'x'),('b',4,'y')])     
[3, 4]
```

I was able to run this successfully using :

```
x[1] for x in elements
```

but the second test was not successful which is:

```
>>> extract_second([('c',5,'z'),('d',6)])
[5, None]
```

then i used the following code to work it out by a little bit research

```
lst=[(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]

for i in lst:
    if len(i) != 3:
        print "None"
    else:
        print i[1],
```

Earlier I was able to print the output as required but brackets and comma was not included in it

Expected outcome:

```
[3,4]
[5, None]
```

Received output:

```
3 4
5 None
```

Answer (score 1):

You are `print`ing in the loop rather than constructing a new list:

```
result = []
for i in lst:
    if len(i) != 3:
        result.append(None)
    else:
        result.append(i[1])
return result
```

Should give you the expected output.

Note: you could still do this with a list comprehension:

```
>>> elements = [('c',5,'z'),('d',6)]
>>> [x[1] if len(x) == 3 else None for x in elements]
[5, None]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering the question AChampion. I forgot to mention one more test as we are using doctest.   >>> >>>extract_second([('a',3,'x'),('b',4,'y')]) ==  [3, 4]
 True                                                                                                    (I'm unable to get this value as True idk why) could you please help and is there any easier way to do so as i'm new to python  and still learning to understand how the control works.

Comment: I don't see your issue.

Comment: def extract_second(triples):
    """Given a list of triples, return a list with the second element of each triple

    If an item is not a triple, return None for that element

    >>> extract_second([('a',3,'x'),('b',4,'y')])
    [3, 4]
    >>> extract_second([('c',5,'z'),('d',6)])
    [5, None]
    >>> extract_second([('a',3,'x'),('b',4,'y')]) ==  [3, 4]
    True
    """
    lst = triples

    print [x[1] if len(x) == 3 else None for x in lst]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest

    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)         (This is the complete program)